# React.js - state variable is undefined when app is uploaded to Amplify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify, use-state

I'm having a very strange error and can not figure out what is going on. Just to summarize, I have a dialog with a jsonschema form and an image that is uploaded to an input and saved in b64 format in a state variable created with useState

Here is the most relevant part of the code

```
const AddCategoriaDialog = (props) => {
    const { onClose, open, token, actualizaCategorias, categorias } = props;
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [b64Image, setB64Image] = useState(undefined);
    const [uploadingPhoto, setUploadingPhoto] = useState(false);
    const [thereIsImage, setThereIsImage] = useState(false);

    const submitButtonRef = useRef();
    const inputRef = useRef();

    const readFileAsync = (file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => {
                resolve(reader.result);
            };
            reader.onerror = reject;
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
    };

    const onChangeFile = async (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('Setting uploadingPhoto to true');
        setUploadingPhoto(true);
        let file = await readFileAsync(event.target.files[0]);
        setB64Image(file);
        setThereIsImage(true);
        setUploadingPhoto(false);
        console.log('Setting uploadingPhoto to false');
    };

    const onSubmit = async () => {
        console.log('[AddCategory] saving: ', {
            ...formData,
            img: b64Image,
        });
        console.log('image b64 is: ', b64Image);
        await axios
            .post(
                `${API_URL}/carta/categoria`,
                {
                    ...formData,
                    img: b64Image,
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'X-Api-Key': process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token.idToken}`,
                    },
                }
            )
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    let newCategorias = categorias;
                    newCategorias.push({
                        id: response.data.data,
                        ...formData,
                        img: b64Image,
                    });
                    actualizaCategorias(newCategorias);
                    setLoading(false);
                    onClose();
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setLoading(false);
                console.error(err);
            });
    };
```

So, my issue is that sometimes, b64Image in console.log() of onSubmit function is undefined under determined conditions. It happens when I follow these steps:

1. I fill in a form
2. I upload a picture
3. I execute onSubmit function

but if I follow steps in the order 2., 1. and 3., b64Image has the value as expected.

Furthermore, this issue only happens when I make amplify publish and run the app from amazon, because if I run the react project locally, everything works fine and in onSubmit() function the b64Image variable has the value it is expected.

I have been a couple days trying to understand why this happens but has no clue yet.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

It looks like the problem comes from using react-jsonschema-form.

As I said, i have a jsonschema form:

```
                        <Form
                            schema={categoria.schema}
                            uiSchema={categoria.uischema}
                            formData={formData}
                            onChange={(e) => setFormData(e.formData)}
                            onSubmit={onSubmit}
                        >
                            <Button
                                ref={submitButtonRef}
                                onClick={onSubmit()}
                                style={{ display: 'none' }}
                            />
                        </Form>
```

and then, in the dialog button i click the form submit button using the submitButtonRef

```
<Button
                    onClick={() => submitButtonRef.current.click()}
                    // onClick={onSubmit}
                    color='primary'
                    disabled={uploadingPhoto}
                >
                    {uploadingPhoto ? <CircularProgress /> : <>Save</>}
                </Button>
```

I have checked that if instead of submiting with submit button ref I directly call onSubmit() from the dialog button, everything works fine.

So it looks like the state variables are somehow not ready to be accesed the button ref executes onSubmit.

Still not understanding what is going on...

Comment: This is happening because your form is submitting form without the image on uploading condition. Hold your form submit `thereIsImage` till you are getting it true.

Comment: Thank you all for your response. I found a clue and will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you assert you await onChangeFile finished before calling onSubmit ? I don't see that part in your code

Maybe readFileAsync execute instantaneously on local but can take some seconds to upload the file on the server (which make your variable undefined)

Comment: I can, onChangeFile is for sure finished before calling onSubmit.

Answer (score 0):

As photo is read asynchronously from computer, it will certainly take some time to have defined value.

So, when you follow **step 1 -> 2 -> 3**, Once you click Submit, at that time photo has not been read completely.

But, when you follow **step 2 -> 1 -> 3**, Photo is properly read because you have given enough time in filling the form.

**Solution**: Enable Submit button only when photo is read completely asynchronously from computer.

**Note**: It will work on local because the photo will be read in no time but on cloud as they don't put everything on same system, So there could be some delay while reading it from different system.

Comment: Don think this is the problem since I can fill the form (1), upload the image (2) and wait a long time before submit the form, so in theory there is enough time to load the image but the result still being the same; b64image is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. It was on the children button in form. I had to change Button from material component to normal html button, remove onClick and add type="submit". The correct is:

```
<Form
  schema={categoria.schema}
  uiSchema={categoria.uischema}
  formData={formData}
  onChange={(e) => setFormData(e.formData)}
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
>
  <button
    type="submit"
    ref={submitButtonRef}
    style={{ display: 'none' }}
  />
</Form>
```